# Explain this step in lecture notes

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, mathematical-physics

The bounty offered is for the person that explains me how the author gets from equation 3.19 to equation 3.20 in these lecture [see here](http://www.ueltschi.org/teaching/2007-StatMech.pdf). Normally I would agree that copying the relevant equation would be meaningful, but as this is a part of a longer proof, I think that you need to look at the context in order to understand the question.
 am thinking about a step in the proof of the equivalence of ensembles in [StatMech on page 25. step from 3.19 to 3.20](http://www.ueltschi.org/teaching/2007-StatMech.pdf).

It seems to be argued there that for $A$ and $K$ large enough, the term

$$\sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \int_{-Bn}^{\infty} 1_{\text{{N>K or u>A}}}(u)e^{-\beta |\lambda_m|(\frac{u}{2}+n)}du $$

becomes arbitrarily small (We have $N = \frac{n}{|\lambda _m|}$ and $|\lambda_m| = \int_{\lambda_m}dx$), as the essential thing is to replace this whole term by $e^{\beta |\lambda_m|p(\beta, \mu)}$. $\beta, B$ are larger than zero.

Despite, I do not really trust this step cause if we assume that only $N>K$, then it seems to be necessary for this whole expression to converge that $B$ is in $(0,2)$. Thus, there seems to be an additional requirement regarding $B$ in this step. Does anybody see if there is an additional trick used here or am I just missing something?

In particular, I doubt that $$\sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \int_{-Bn}^{0} 1_{\text{{N>K or u>A}}}(u)e^{-\beta |\lambda_m|(\frac{u}{2}+n)}du $$ converges in general.

The thing is that if we assume $N>K$, then we have $$\sum_{N=K+1}^{\infty} \int_{-B \frac{N}{|\lambda_m|}}^{0} e^{-\beta |\lambda_m|(\frac{u}{2}+n)}du $$ and this expression converges even for large $K$ only if $B<2$, wouldn't you agree?- So I just don't understand this step.
If you have any questions,  please let me know.

Comment: It's not available.

Comment: the lecture notes? well, I can open the link, but if you have any troubles: http://www.ueltschi.org/teaching/2007-StatMech.pdf

Comment: While I can appreciate why you'd indicate that the reader should consult the actual proof in the notes, I'd still suggest you indicate in your question the type of result you're trying to establish.

Comment: The notation does not make sense, what does $|\lambda_m|=\int_{\lambda_m} dx$ mean?  If  $N$ is an index of the summation, then shouldn't it be an integer?  And why does $\lambda_m$ have a subscript $m$?

Comment: There also seems to be some mistake in substituting $-Bn = -B N/|\lambda_m|$, when the definition suggests it should be $-Bn=-BN|\lambda_m|$.